# Object reference issue in Python while creating a tree

Tags: python, python-3.x, tree

I'm trying to construct a tree from a list in python. The nodes in my tree have values of indices of my list, and the parent of each node will be the node specified in the list at that index.
In the code sample below, `varlist` stores the node elements of the tree with values in the input `array`.
For example, an input list of [-1, 0, 4, 0, 3] should give the following tree:

```
  0
 / \
1   3
     \
      4
       \
        2
```

The way I'm doing this is to first initialize the nodes separately in a list with default parent as None. Then I'm assigning the parent and child as I traverse the array as follows:

```
class Node1:
    def __init__(self, val, parent, children = []):
        self.val = val
        if parent == -1:
            self.parent = None
        else:
            self.parent = parent
        self.children = children
    def __str__(self):
        return(str(self.val))

def treeHeight(array):
    varlist = [0] * len(array)
    for i in range(len(array)):
        varlist[i] = Node1(i, None)
    for i in range(len(varlist)):
        if array[i] != -1:
            varlist[i].parent = varlist[array[i]]
            varlist[array[i]].children.append(varlist[i])
        else:
            root = varlist[i]
    for i in range(len(array)):
        print(varlist[i].val,varlist[i].parent, varlist[i].children)
    return(None)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(treeHeight([-1, 0, 4, 0, 3]))
```

The output I get is this:

```
0 None [<__main__.Node1 object at 0x1041051d0>, <__main__.Node1 object at 0x104105208>, <__main__.Node1 object at 0x104105780>, <__main__.Node1 object at 0x104105cc0>]
1 0 [<__main__.Node1 object at 0x1041051d0>, <__main__.Node1 object at 0x104105208>, <__main__.Node1 object at 0x104105780>, <__main__.Node1 object at 0x104105cc0>]
2 4 [<__main__.Node1 object at 0x1041051d0>, <__main__.Node1 object at 0x104105208>, <__main__.Node1 object at 0x104105780>, <__main__.Node1 object at 0x104105cc0>]
3 0 [<__main__.Node1 object at 0x1041051d0>, <__main__.Node1 object at 0x104105208>, <__main__.Node1 object at 0x104105780>, <__main__.Node1 object at 0x104105cc0>]
4 3 [<__main__.Node1 object at 0x1041051d0>, <__main__.Node1 object at 0x104105208>, <__main__.Node1 object at 0x104105780>, <__main__.Node1 object at 0x104105cc0>]
```

The output is not what I'm expecting because somehow, the `children` list of all the nodes have 4 elements in them, when I was expecting 2 of them to have 2 children and the rest empty. Can someone please help me explain what is going on here?

Comment: You have a mutable default argument in `__init__`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you need to know the difference between the `__repr__` and `__str__`. In this case, you are try yo **represent** the `Node1` object you created, as the  **repr** aims at a complete string representation of the object; while the **str** is only to return a nicely string for printing. You should actually define the `__repr__`. In your case, `__str__` function you implemented is actually not used at all.

Another thing is that you should never use the mutable object as the default arguments in python function, it is really a bad practice, as:

> Passing mutable lists or dictionaries as default arguments to a function can have unforeseen consequences. Usually when a programmer uses a list or dictionary as the default argument to a function, the programmer wants the program to create a new list or dictionary every time that the function is called. However, this is not what Python does. The first time that the function is called, Python creates a persistent object for the list or dictionary. Every subsequent time the function is called, Python uses that same persistent object that was created from the first call to the function.

```
class Node1:
    def __init__(self, val, parent, children = ()): # default argument should be immutable
        self.val = val
        if parent == -1:
            self.parent = None
        else:
            self.parent = parent
        if not isinstance(children, list):
            children = list(children)
        self.children = children
    def __str__(self):
        return(str(self.val))

    def __repr__(self):
        return(str(self.val)) # need to define __repr__

def treeHeight(array):
    varlist = [0] * len(array)
    for i in range(len(array)):
        varlist[i] = Node1(i, None)
    for i in range(len(varlist)):
        if array[i] != -1:
            varlist[i].parent = varlist[array[i]]
            varlist[array[i]].children.append(varlist[i])
        else:
            root = varlist[i]
    for i in range(len(array)):
        print(varlist[i].val,varlist[i].parent, varlist[i].children)
    return(None)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('\n\n')
    print(treeHeight([-1, 0, 4, 0, 3]))
```

Generally, the best practice is to use Use a sentinel value to denote an empty list or dictionary:

```
class Node1:
    def __init__(self, val, parent=None, child=None): # default argument should be immutable
        self.val = val
        self.children= []
        if parent and parent.val != -1:
            self.parent = parent
        else:
            self.parent = None
        if child:
            self.children.append(child)

#    def __str__(self):
#        return(str(self.val))

    def __repr__(self):
        return(str(self.val)) # need to define __repr__

def treeHeight(arr): # array is reverse attribute in python, use arr instead
    varlist = []
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        varlist.append(Node1(i))
    for i in range(len(varlist)):
        if arr[i]!=-1:
            varlist[i].parent = varlist[arr[i]]
            varlist[arr[i]].children.append(varlist[i])
        else:
            root = varlist[i]

    for i in range(len(arr)):
        print(varlist[i].val,varlist[i].parent, varlist[i].children)
    return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('\n\n')
    treeHeight([-1, 0, 4, 0, 3])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This really helped. I'll remember the immutable arguments rule.

Comment: @Kamal, i'm glad it helps. And to deal with it, the best practice is to use a sentinel value to denote an empty list or dictionary.